# Modify variable in rst with pandoc

Tags: latex, restructuredtext, pandoc

I'm converting a `.rst` document to `.tex` with `pandoc` and I would like to modify variables, such as `$date` in the `.rst` document. I'm using:

```
============
My doc title
============

:Date: October

My first title
==============

Lipsum…
```

The variable is indeed overridden, but using field lists like this generates a definition section in the resulting LaTeX document:

```
\title{My doc title}
\date{Octobre}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{description}
\end{description}
```

This empty `description` makes LaTeX compilation fail. When I don't use field lists, it disappears.

How can I avoid this `description` section while using field lists in my RST document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in pandoc, which I just fixed.  (The fix will be in the next release, but if you  need it now, you can compile the development version: see [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc-1.10) for instructions.)

Note also that pandoc currently only recognizes author, title, and date as metadata fields.  If you're expecting other fields to set template variables, you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Thank you. I might write to you regarding other bugs/features (or do you actually like it if I ask here?)